# WiFi doesn't work on Debian

Tags: debian, wifi, iwlwifi

I have Debian Jessie installed on my laptop. I can't get my WiFi to work. In Wicd Network Manager it says there are no available wireless networks.

Running `lspci` gives me:

```
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83).
```

I have tried everything I found on the internet such as editing `/etc/network/interfaces`, installing drivers, updating, installing other things, editing more .conf files, etc. I just can't connect to WiFi. Ethernet works but sometimes I will need to use WiFi. I have Debian Jessie installed on my laptop. I can't get my WiFi to work! Anyone have any ideas how to get my WiFi working?

Comment: `apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi` from the non-free repositories.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have done that.

Answer (score 4):

According to the official website , [the Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) is supported by the kernel version `4.1` and higher.

to get the wifi install the latest kernel from backports

Edit your `sources.list` by adding the following line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Update and search for available `linux-image`'s :

```
apt update
apt-cache search linux-image
```

Install the latest, e,g:

```
apt install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

or

```
apt install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64-unsigned
```

Reboot your system

Download the required driver:

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-3160-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
```

Copy it to your `/lib/firmware`:

```
tar xvf iwlwifi-3160-ucode-16.242414.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-3160-ucode-16.242414.0
cp iwlwifi-3160-ucode* /lib/firmware
modprobe iwlwifi
```

To solve the `unmet dependencies` error , run:

```
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-base
```

As motioned [@ Rui F Ribeiro](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/138261/rui-f-ribeiro), Installing the next stable release (debian 9) should be the best solution to deal with intel driver witch depends on the most recent kernel release on debian.

Comment: I have not tried this. I will tell you if it works.

Comment: +1 for 4.1/backports mentioning. I would also add that if you are installing from scratch, better go directly to Stretch/Debian 9 as it will be out in a couple of days.

Comment: When I try to run `apt install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64` I get this:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 : Depends: linux-base (>= 4.3~) but 3.5 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @6EQUJ5 Right! see my edit please

Comment: @GAD3R I nearly ran the wrong command until I saw your edit.

Comment: Hmmmm `apt install linux-image...` should be made *after* installing iwlwifi. Otherwise when rebooting, it wont go up, as it did not make into initrd. I would sugest `dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64` to correct this.

Comment: @GAD3R Update: I tried installing linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 and rebooted... I couldn't even login because the mouse and keyboard didn't work. So I went into grub command line and booted from vmlinuz.old and initrd.img.old. Now what.

Comment: From the advanced option of Grub Menu boot the old kernel (3.16) then run `apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel` and reboot

Comment: @GAD3R That didn't fix my mouse and keyboard not working when I booted with the 4.9.0-0 kernel.

Comment: Install the `linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64-unsigned`

Comment: When installing that image I got: `Error! Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 cannot be found.
Please install the linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 package,
Your kernel headers for kernel 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 cannot be found.
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
Please install the linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 package,
or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located`. Also tons of "possible missing firmware". I then tried installing *linux-headers-4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64*.

Comment: Then, I got `Error! Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.9.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 (x86_64)`.

Comment: @GAD3R That command does not work for me (even with root privileges): `bash: xserver-xorg-input-all: command not found`. Also, I had to reinstall `xserver-xorg-video-intel` since I couldn't change my brightness. It seems like everything has been done to prevent me from connecting to WiFi.

Comment: @GAD3R I already did that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54743/discussion-between-gad3r-and-6equj5).